# NUnit check that property is a collection

Tags: tdd, nunit

TDD related question.

I can check that property Years is `List<int>`:

```
Assert.IsInstanceOf<List<int>>(viewModel.Years);
```

But Years can be `List<int>` or object that contains `List<int>`.

For example

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public List<int> Years {get;set;}
   or 
   public object Years {get;set;}
}
```

I'm asking this because while coding VS generates Years property of type object.

One possible solution can be:

```
Assert.AreEqual(yearsList, (List<int>)viewModel.Years);
```

When I will generate Years, it will be of `List<int>` type.

Are there another ways to ensure that Years is of correct type?

Answer (score 2):

Bypassing the question of whether or not you should even be testing this, at a minimum, instead of testing that `Years` is a `List<int>` you should be testing that it is an `IList<int>`. Second, do you really need something that strong? Can you get away with `ICollection<int>` or `IEnumerable<int>`. You should be testing the weakest type that you need.

Then, I would say:

```
static class ObjectExtensions {
    public static bool Implements(this object o, Type type) {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(o != null);
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(type != null);
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(type.IsInterface);
        return o.GetType()
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Contains(type);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[Test]
public void Years_is_an_object_that_implements_ilist_int() {
    // viewModel is ViewModel
    Assert.IsNotNull(viewModel.Years);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, viewModel.Years.Implements(typeof(IList<int>));
}
```

Comment: If I understand right. The question actually is: How to force VS generate right type for property stub instead of object.

Comment: @Sergey Mirvoda: The question is titled "NUnit...." and is tagged "tdd" and "nunit". I don't think that this about Visual Studio.

Comment: @denis_n: Your comment didn't clarify anything.

Comment: Sorry Jason, I have problems with my English (I'm still learning it). Sergey is correct - I needed a way to force VS generate property of a right type, not just of an Object type.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me is this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(viewModel.Years is List<int>)
```

but it doesn't work:( even in resharper

only working and nice looking way is this:

```
Assert.IsNotNull(viewModel.Years as List<int>)
```

FYI
ReSharper also is not smart enough to determine right type.

Answer (score 0):

I took the best from both answers:

My solution

```
namespace Tests
{
    public class AssertExt
    {
        public static void IsOfType<T>(T entity) 
        {
        }


        public static void IsOfType<T>(T entity, string message) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I can now write something like this:

```
AssertExt.IsOfType<Dictionary<int, string>>(viewModel.PrintFor);
```

And VS will generate property of correct type.

Unfortunately I can't create an extension for NUnit's Assert class.

I don't know why it doesn't allow me to have something like

```
Assert.IsOfType<Dictionary<int, string>>(viewModel.PrintFor);
```

Maybe the problem is the Assert's protected constructor?